# Use https with only http supporting node-xmpp-bosh

Tags: node.js, apache, node-xmpp, converse.js

## Intro

I use [converse.js](https://conversejs.org/) for as XMPP webclient. Therefore I need a bosh server that handles the bidirectional communication.
As such a server acts [node-xmpp-bosh](https://github.com/dhruvbird/node-xmpp-bosh). Since my site is SSL/TLS encrypted and it's only available through https, it's only allowed to connect to the bosh server by encrypted communication.
Unfortunately node-xmpp-bosh doesn't support SSL/TLS.

## Question

Can I circumvent this, by forwarding the traffic somehow? Or am I lost and need to search another bosh server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hours later...again happy :)

The solution to my problem is to proxy the traffic to the bosh server. To do this on Apache I use now (or at least at the moment) this VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName bosh.domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.bosh.domain.tld

    ServerAdmin admin@domain.tld

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5280/http-bind/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5280/http-bind/


    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/chain.pem
    SSLVerifyClient None
    # HSTS (mod_headers is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
</VirtualHost>
```